# Kotlin For Loop Timing

Tags: android, firebase, for-loop, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

So I'm attempting to match make two players into a game and am struggling with the for loop execution timing. I'm using firebase firestore as my backend btw. I want each for loop iteration to wait until the last one is done because each transaction inside the loop take a second or two and I only want to join one game. Right now it basically joins all the empty games because the for loop does not wait for the last loop to be completed. I believe this is a asynchrous/synchrnous problem.

Here is my for loop code:

```
for (document: DocumentSnapshot in task.result) {
                            firestoreInstance.runTransaction(Transaction.Function<Void> { transaction ->
                                val snapshot = transaction.get(document.reference)
                                transaction.update(document.reference, "joiner", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid)

                                // Success
                                null
                            }).addOnSuccessListener {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Transaction success!")
                                onComplete(document.reference)
                                gameJoined = true
                            }.addOnFailureListener { e ->
                                Log.w(TAG, "Transaction failure.", e)
                                onComplete(null)
                            }
                        }
```

Any advice would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use recursion:

```
fun myLoopOrWhatever(result: List<DocumentSnapshot>, index: Int) {
    val doc = result[index]

    firestoreInstance.runTransaction(Transaction.Function<Void> { transaction -> 
        val snapshot = transaction.get(doc.reference)
        transation.update(doc.reference, "joiner", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid)
        null
    }).addOnSuccessListener {
        //your logic
        if (index < result.size) myLoopOrWhatever(result, index++)
    }.addOnFailureListener { e -> 
        //your logic
        if (index < result.size) myLoopOrWhatever(result, index++)
    }
}
```

Start it off by passing `task.result` and `0`.

I'm just guessing that `task.result` is a List object. It may be an ArrayList or something else. You might have to adjust that type.

Comment: I actually tried that before but slightly differently. This worked. Thanks!